# How to add validation to a always editable column Syncfusion Angular

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I am using a syncfusion grid.
Setting the editSettings to true enables editing a column on double click. But I want the cell to be editable always. So I used template for the column that is to be made as editable. But now I am not able to use validation for the editable column.

Making the template as syncfusion TextBox does not work either